# PhpStorm: file watcher / Less: trigger execution for extra directory in the project

Tags: phpstorm, less, webstorm, file-watcher

I configured compiling `.less` for my current project with works fine.

I've added an extra folder to the project which also contains `.less` files and I also want PhpStorm to trigger the Less compiler when changing something inside there. Unfortunately it doesn't work ..

I already tried changing the scope in the Less configuration.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well.. show your File Watcher settings (all fields, including collapsed); the scope etc... By default all file watcher work with all files of that file type. Quite likely it will be your settings.